# Meaning of "ci tengo a precisare che"

Tags: meaning

What would be the meaning of the expression

> "Ci tengo a precisare che"?

Google Translator is giving me this expression as a translation of

> "I would like to point out that..."

The translation does not seem to be literal. It seems like a idiomatic expression of some sort.

I am sorry if my question is too obvious. I am a beginner learner of Italian.

Comment: What does your dictionary say about "tenerci a"?

Comment: "Tenere a qualcosa" = "To care about something"

Comment: @DonHolgo it says " to care about, attach great importance to".

Comment: @DanielZardo Exactly. So doesn't that answer your question already?

Comment: @DonHolgo yeah, I've marked as answered already.

Comment: @DanielZardo I was just wondering why you had to ask here in the first place, seeing that the dictionary already tells you that it _is_ an idiomatic expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The translation is pretty good, although `"Ci tengo a precisare che"` is a mildly strong expression that `"I would like to point out that..."` does not catch perfectly, at least in my opinion.

A slightly better translation could be something like `"I care to point out that..."`